# problems while running a rails proyect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am about to continue the project of another programmer and the person who contacted me sent me the code, I just installed all the gems and I am using the correct version of ruby but when doing "rails s" does not start the server, I enter the folder of the project but I see that there are not some folders that are usually in my rails projects at the time of creating the project. How the project is currently running on a server I don't know if they have dispensed with these folders or I'm missing something, the structure of the project is structured in the image, I would be very grateful if you could answer my question.[image]
[image: gemfile] [image: and the console]

apparently the project makes use of the rbenv-vars gem

Comment: my 2 cents: never use Windows for Ruby on Rails development (use Ubuntu or MacOS). Otherwise, you will be lost in installing a ton of missing packages.

Comment: The `bin` directory in the project hence the error. You should try to check for that.

Comment: Also check for the PATH variable. If your executables are located on some other path then you might have to check if the path variable is updated accordingly.